# USB-C Debug Accessory Mode and USB 2.0

Tags: embedded, usb, segger-jlink

I want to build an embedded device which is using a USB-C for debugging purposes and USB 2 functionality.

Now I am not sure whether or not I understood the USB-C Standard correctly.

1. Is it correct, that if I connect the CC1 and CC2 to pin with a pulldown of 5.1 kOHM to GND that other devices detect the debug accessory mode and therefore is it save for a connecting device that none of the 14 pins are used?
2. Is it still possible to use the USB 2 pins for USB 2.1 purposes?

The idea is, that I  short-circuit the pairs Axx and Bxx and connect SWD-Signals to the Pins A11,A10,A8, A2,A3 and vice versa for B and connect USB 2 to the D+/D- Pins as well.

3. Is there a tool I am able to detect from a computer in which mode a device is?

Thx for your help

Comment: I've no idea what USB 2.1 is supposed to mean but this question is off topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about hardware, not programming, and should be asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead. Note that tool recommendations are off-topic on both sites so you have to remove 3) from the question or rephrase it as "How can I detect from a computer in which mode..."